# Deploying different version grails application (war) under JBoss 4.2?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I want to deploy two Grails WAR under same JBoss server. 
One I use Grails 1.2.1 and another one with Grails 2.0.

Is this possible? if yes, please let me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about JBoss, but with tomcat, we have several older grails apps in 1.3.4 and now use 2.0. I can deploy both, the only difference is when I create the WAR files, I have to make sure I am using the correct grails version. You can use a script to automatically do this.

Ex: In unix

```
export GRAILS_HOME=~/src/grails-1.3.4    >> Depends on path where you installed
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_23/   >> Depends on path where you installed
export MAVEN_HOME=/opt/maven   >> Depends on path where you installed

export PATH=/home/eng/src/grails-1.3.7/bin:/opt/maven/bin/
```

Source this when creating the WAR file for a 1.3.4 version. Do a similar method when creating the other version.

Basically the grails version is independent from its deployment.